# How to append a variable to CURL command

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I am trying to use `curl qrenco.de/google.com` with an alias so that the alias takes the input parameter `google.com` and appends it to `curl qrenco.de/`. i want it to look something like this:
`$qrcode google.com`

i have tried the following:
`alias qrcode='curl qrenco.de/$(read)'`

but this doesn't seem to work. i am new to bash and would like to know the right approach.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Isn't it what you need locally to your Linux system, rather than one more occasion to give-up your data to GAFAMs for a mundane feature? See: `qrencode` man-page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/qrencode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every time an alias gives you trouble, you should just be using a function.

```
qrcode() { curl qrenco.de/"$1"; }
```

Comment: thank you. i have found a work around using a similar command `alias qrcode='f(){ curl qrenco.de/"$@"; unset -f f; }; f'` but could not understand this. can you help me with this?

Comment: what does `unset -f f;` mean?

Comment: `unset` removes something like a variable from the env. `-f` says the thing is a function. In this example, the name of the function is `f`. What that does is uses an alias to create a function every time that un-creates itself when it runs - then call the function. Seems silly to me. Just drop the alias and make a function instead. Why use both to create exactly the same function over and over?